# Resetting defaults on Canon T3i?

Tags: canon, camera-settings

I recently purchased a used Canon T3i at the pawn shop down the street and just wondered, is there any way to reset the camera to it's factory defaults or the way it came from the factory new?  I've looked thru the manual on the Canon site but have not found anything about this yet.  The previous owner must have been a pro because he has a lot of very specific settings which I don't care to use yet.

Comment: A web search for "Canon T3i reset to factory defaults" might give what you need...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See page 176 of the [manual](http://gdlp01.c-wss.com/gds/0/0300004720/02/eosrt3i-eos600d-im2-c-en.pdf):

(disclaimer: bad attempt to translate iconography to text in the following!)

> The camera's shooting settings and menu settings can be reverted to the default. This option is available in Creative Zone modes.
>
> 1. Select [Clear settings]
>      Under the [spanner with three dots] tab, select [Clear settings], then press <SET>.
> 2. Select [Clear all camera settings]
>      Select [Clear all camera settings], then press <SET>.
> 3. Select [OK]
>      Select [OK], then press <SET>.
>      Selecting [Clear all camera settings] will reset the camera to the default settings on the next page *[of the manual]*.

The manual then notes you should also select the [Clear all Custom Func. (C.Fn)] option in the same menu to clear custom functions as well.